# How to change url logo at run time

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

```
 <head>
     <title id="Title" runat="server"></title>
     <link id="TitleLogo" runat="server" rel="shortcut icon" href="Images/TM32.ico"/>  
 </head>
```

Here I added in head tag title with the link where I am adding image. I want to change that at run time.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please edit your question to give more details of what you are trying & the problem you are having, & also to remove either the c# or vb.net tag.

Comment: Is this code in MasterPage?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using Master page, so that you can change `Href` at runtime by using [`Master.FindControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/master-pages/control-id-naming-in-content-pages-cs):

```
(Master.FindControl("TitleLogo") as HtmlLink).Href = "Images/TM33.ico";
```

Comment: Thank you selim, but I am not using master page.

Comment: Please post any other solution for the same.

Comment: So can't you just `TitleLogo.Href = "Images/TM33.ico";` in .cs?

Comment: I want it for .vb

Answer (score 0):

Once you have added the "runat" and "id" fields you should have access to it in your code behind in any of the life cycle methods as an HtmlGenericControl.

C#

```
protected HtmlGenericControl TitleLogo;

private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   if(!Page.IsPostBack)
   {
      TitleLogo.Attributes["href"] = "Images/TM33.ico";
   }
}
```

And in VB

```
    Protected TitleLogo As HtmlGenericControl

    Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            TitleLogo.Attributes("href") = "Images/TM33.ico"
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Can you be more specific please. Do you get an error? Are you saying  the icon has not changed? Please make sure you look at the HTML source code as you will find the shortcut icon is cached by your browser.

Comment: actually while inspecting the page in the head section image is added in href tag but it not shown in browser.

Comment: You will find the shortcut icon is agressively cached in most broswers as it rarely changes in normal circumstances. To test try using a different browser or a different computer if you can (or even a different URL if your dev environment allows).